# How to pass time in "highcharts"?

Tags: php, highcharts

i am passing data like this

```
$chart->series[] = array('data' => array());
in array i have data in string  
1 => string '11:03:01' (length=8)
2 => string '11:07:56' (length=8)
```

How i pass this time data in bar charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to send just a time, directly.

How to handle measuring times will depend on what exactly you're trying to do.
If you want to use time on your x axis to track data throughout the day, the best method is to use the full date time string, sent as an epoch timestamp  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time )

If you are tracking data by time, but not for a particular date, you will still need to use the full date stamp - in such a case, if you are tracking multiple dates in multiple series, you will need to use the **same date** for each series, appending the individual time stamps to the 'base' date.

For various other uses, sending a number value instead of a time value will work better (ie if you want to send 10 hours, 30 minutes, you can send 10.5 instead of 10:30)

Comment: Its better idea, to use this technique by dividing minutes With 60.
But its best to use time in x-axis and days of current month in Y axis. i am trying if its possible.

Comment: almost anything is possible with enough work. Some things are easier than others.  If you can put together an example of what you want, you'll be able to get a lot more help.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in two ways,

1. UTC format like [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
2. Unix Timestamp like 1262307661000

Highcharts accepts both of them,

Hope this will help you to achieve what you need.

Comment: where i use [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
and whats 29.9 ?

Comment: Use this where you want to send the time. 29.9 is the data value, if you want to send only time exclude it

Answer (score -1):

process the array with times in a loop and add each item to a variable that is seperated by comma..

then finally put

```
series: [<?php echo $str;?>]
```

assuming **$str** contains values:

```
$str = "'11:03:01', '11:07:56'";
```