# Day vs Time on Scatter plot

Tags: datetime, highcharts, unix-timestamp

I want to have a day vs timescatter plot. I have some unix time values. I just need to plot them on X and Y axis such that the days of the week (e.g. Monday, Tuseday etc.) on the X axis and the time e.g.(2:24,13:40 etc. ) on the Y axis. I have tried using the datetime type. But I think I am missing something.

Here is what I have tried to do:

```
        data=[["Saturday", 1390723133.57414], ["Sunday", 1390803027.3852], ["Monday", 1390862581.18321], ["Monday", 1390830748.67335], ["Wedneday", 1391015403.93726], ["Wedneday", 1391006992.20059], ["Sunday", 1390804961.8415]]

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'scatter',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'test'
            },

            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    enabled: true,
                    text: 'Day of the week'
                },
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: true,
                showLastLabel: true,

            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Time of the day'
                },
                type: 'datetime',

            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 100,
                y: 70,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 5,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: '',
                color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                data: data


            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227847/how-to-pass-time-in-highcharts/21268457#21268457

Answer (score 0):

You need parse your data to correct format, because in data array you need to have timestamps or numbers, not days / strings as you have.