# HighCharts Hours/Minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to display a bar chart with hours / minutes in high chart. I don't want anything to do with the date, just hours / minutes. This is for a timesheet app to log hours for projects. I want to see how many hours/minutes have been spent. All the information I've seen so far involves using dates / 24 hour time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can use [columnRange](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange) with datetime yAxis.

Answer (score 0):

Hours and minutes is really just a numeric value.  You can send it is total number of minutes, or as x.x hours.

If you really want the hh:mm formatting, you can do that in the formatter for the axis labels, tooltip, and data labels.

see answer here also:
[How to pass time in "highcharts"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227847/how-to-pass-time-in-highcharts/21268457#21268457)