# Using hours and minutes as data in highcharts donut chart

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart, dataformat

I got a donut chart and want to display hours and minutes. Using highcharts pie chart with constant visible drilldown data this leads me to a big problem, please see the picture first:

[image: hours and minutes problem]

The inner blue slice has the value 10.40, which stands for 10:40 as a time. The two outer slices have the values 5.50 and 4.50, which, summed up as hours and minutes, results in 10.40, but highcharts doesn't know it's a time format, so it sums that up as 10.00 which perfectly shows my problem.

I tried setting the yAxis type to datetime

```
type: 'datetime',
```

which does not change anything so far. I found other entries like [Pass time values to Highcharts Column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493021/pass-time-values-to-highcharts-column-chart), which sadly left me clueless.

Did I miss something? Glad for any help.

Comment: Well in what form do you receive your time information? Can you manipulate it as you wish? If so, I think `datetime` is the way to go.

Comment: I can manipulate it as I wish. But I only need hours and minutes. If datetime is the right thing, could you give me a valid example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An minimal example solution, using millisecond values to only display hours and minutes ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6606gvx1/1/)):

```
var m = 1000 * 60;
var h = m * 60;

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return  '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', new Date(this.y));
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Inner',
        data: [
            { name: 'A', y: (10 * h) + (40 * m), color: 'blue' }, 
            { name: 'B', y: (3 * h), color: 'red' }, 
        ],
        size: '60%'
    }, {
        name: 'Outer',
        data: [
            { name: 'A1', y: (5 * h) + (50 * m), color: 'blue' }, 
            { name: 'A2', y: (4 * h) + (50 * m), color: 'blue' }, 
            { name: 'B1', y: (3 * h), color: 'red' }, 
        ],
        size: '100%',
        innerSize: '60%'
    }]
});
```

Here we just operate with time going from 0 and out. The tooltip is used to format the values in a readable format.

See [this more elaborate JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/bmv5e8v7/1/) using some of the [pie-donut demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/) code to color the slices like your example picture.

Comment: As I was writing this I realized `datetime` is irrelevant, as you don't really gain anything from it, compared to just numeric values. You have to do the tooltip-formatting anyways. Setting `yAxis.type` to `datetime` changes nothing in the above example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks good. I will try and comment tomorrow :)

Comment: It's this simple but yet perfect. Thanks a lot for your answer.